# Layout - android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new in the android world and I would like to make an android interface of this kind:
http://android.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/picplz-sc.jpg
(screen of the left)

However, i added two icons to my xml but these icons are not beside... (not on the same line)

The xml is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ABABAB">

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+navigate/title" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/myimg" android:layout_marginTop="30px" />

 <ImageView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+navigate/bookings" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/inventory" android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:layout_marginRight="150px"
 />  

 <ImageView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+navigate/picture" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/picture" android:layout_marginLeft="150px"
 /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Is someone has a good tutorial about layout please ? :)
Thx for any help

Comment: this layout is vertical. vertical means one on top of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to read up on layouts. `LinearLayout` is only one of several layouts that are used. Here are some links to helpful tutorials:

http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: @nick glad I could help. Be sure to accept this answer if this is what you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start. It's basic and it helped me: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Also, if you're just starting out with Android layouts, this is a must read article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: No problem, nick. I liked Phil's links better than my first one. But I would still encourage you to read the second link I posted. All of it is worth scanning, but some of it you should read well. There's a section that talks about using "dp" units for objects and "sp" units for text. Using dp's and sp's will allow Android to automatically scale your objects and text for the wide range of screen sizes Android comes in. Using px units should only be done in special cases.